# Where do gcc_qsub, gcc_qmul and gcc_qadd come from?

Tags: c

I am getting the following compilation / link error:

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qsub
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qmul
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qadd
```

What library holds those?

Any ideas?

Lynton

Comment: Are you using `ld` to link?  If so, don't.  Use `gcc` both to compile and to link.

Comment: Hi there, stupid question but how to I let gcc link and not ld?

Comment: By default, `gcc` will compile and link. `gcc -c` compiles only and defers linking. If you invoke `gcc` again (without `-c` this time!) on your compiled object(s), then it will link. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Overall-Options.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a total stab in the dark...

A Google search picked up [this header from Apple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5484/gcc/config/rs6000/darwin-ldouble.c). It looks like its part of `libgcc` (which is not Apple specific, that's just Apple's implementation), and that its used for doing `long double` arithmetic in software. Try adding `-lgcc` to your build process.

[According to the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), you can also explicitly force static or shared linkage of libgcc with either of these options: `-shared-libgcc` or `-static-libgcc`.

**Edit:** As Nemo has pointed out, if you use `gcc` to link instead of manually invoking `ld` yourself, as `libgcc` will then be linked automatically.

Comment: GCC should add that automatically.